# What is so special about IComparable<> as a Generic Constraint

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-constraints

Suppose I have a class

```
Class Apple<T> where T: IComparable<int>{}
```

Now while creating an object for Apple I'll do it like

```
Apple<int> obj = new Apple<int>();
```

The above code will work.

If I replace the same code with any other Generic Interface like `IComparer<>`,`IEnumerable<>` etc.. object creation like the above will not work and we have to declare it like

```
Apple<IEnumerable<int>> obj = new Apple<IEnumerable<int>>();
```

Why is it like that? Why is it the way which i declared for `IComparable<>` is only working for it and not for any other interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing special about [`IComparable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1), but about `T` itself, which - in case of [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32)- also implements [`IComparable<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1). However `int` surely does not implement `IEnumerable<int>`.

Or in other words: you can of course *compare* every `int` with another `int`. However you can´t *iterate* an `int`.